# Has anyone installed 16.04 LTS on NUC6i5SYH or NUC5i5RYH and it worked OTB?

Tags: intel, 16.04, lts, intel-nuc

I am thinking of getting one but keep reading mixed reviews on 16.04 LTS on them. Some say video driver issues. I cannot tell.

Thought I would check here if anyone has installed on these NUCs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use Lubuntu (14.04 and 15.10) on a NUC5i7RYH with an M.2 SSD and it works like a charm. No issues at all, and it runs lightning fast! I haven't installed the 16.04 yet, but I am sure it won't do worse.

Comment: Which M.2 SSD and ram are you using?

Comment: SSD WD Blue 250 GB and RAM 2x8GB Kingstom HyperX Impact

Comment: Haha. Thanks. I actually got it and set it up a few years ago. It's been working great.  Thinking of upgrading to a newer NUC. )